# How to handle exception at runtime in R? (R.net with c#)

Tags: .net, r, c#-4.0, exception

I am currently workin on R.net application using c#.

I am new to R and i am not sure how to handle runtime exceptions in R language? I refered online material on R online but couldnt find useful.

Would try & catch help? or any loop? Please provide me steps.

Please help me. Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The function `tryCatch` is what you are looking for. It works like this:

```
result = tryCatch({
    expr
}, warning = function(w) {
    warning-handler-code
}, error = function(e) {
    error-handler-code
}, finally {
    cleanup-code
}
```

Where `expr` is some R expression that you want to try and run.

Answer (score 0):

try catch finally is likely what you want.  From what I can tell error handling in r.net is the same as error handling in c# / .net.

What you do once you catch the error is always up for debate.  Console.Log , EventLog, swallow, etc.

[Try Catch examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dszsf989%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)